Test to verify that Assembly A does not reference Assembly B always passes
I have written the following NUnit test;
[Test]
public void Assembly1_ShouldNotReference_Assembly2()
{
    var assembly = Assembly.Load("Assembly1");

    var referencedAssemblies = assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();
    var hasReference = referencedAssemblies.Any(a => a.Name == "Assembly2");

    Assert.IsFalse(hasReference);
}

This always passes, even if I add a reference.
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\Assembly2\Assembly2.csproj" />
  <ProjectReference Include="..\Assembly3\Assembly3.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

When I debug the test and inspect the referenced assemblies I do not see Assembly2 in the list, but Assembly3 is there and changing the test to assert that Assembly3 is not referenced causes it to fail.
Types in Assembly3 are used throughout Assembly1, but Assembly2 only exists as a project reference. Ultimately I want to test that Assembly1 never references Assembly2 but why am I seeing this behaviour?

Have you logged all the referenced assemblies to see what they are and if there is just some small string delta? Also, does Assembly1 actually use the reference to Assembly2? The compiler can remove references that aren't actually used

According to this answer, "Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies only includes a particular assembly if you actually use a type in that assembly in your assembly (or a type that you use depends on a type in that assembly". It does not quote a source. But it would seem that "Assembly references" <= "Project references" (as opposed to being equal).

@MarcGravell I only added Assembly2 as a reference but nothing actually uses it, it can be safely removed at any point. If the compiler is removing unecessary references then this test is doing what I need it to
